# Is there an equivalent to BCEL (Java .class manipulation) but in C or C++

Tags: java, c++, c, jvm, .class-file

Is there a C or C++ compatible library for reading and writing Java class files?

I.e. something like Apache BCEL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None that I'm aware of. However, you can call Java from C++. That will let you use BCEL from C++. If you're on one of gcj's supported platforms, you could try using it to compile BCEL to native code.